# UITableView, CollectionView or AutoLayout?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I was using the Uber app last time, and their button group (Paypal, Price Estimate, Promo Code) looked good - Lyft has the same design - and I was wondering how could I achieve the same result in my app ?

[image]

I already tried Layout. I think there's a quicker solution using TableView or CollectionView maybe ? it looks more like a TableView but I don't know how could I put 1 plain row, and then have a row with 2 buttons ...

[image]

In my storyboard I have the above. But I cannot "stick" the 2 buttons to my label, there is a guide-line which block me just below the label.

Hope I was clear enough and in advance sorry for the "No code post".

Thanks for your help !

Comment: I would use Auto Layout. Or, if you target iOS 9, use UIStackViews.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you use a `tableView` the `autoLayout` is required. So try resolving the autoLayout issues.

1. place the buttons alongside
2. provide the following constraints

   1. Button 1:

      1. leading: superview
      2. top: label (set suitable distance)
      3. trailing: button 2
      4. aspectRatio
   2. Button 2:

      1. top: label (same distance as button 1)
      2. trailing: superview
      3. aspectRatio

Also select both the buttons and set equalWidths. Now `Update Frames` and you are good to go.

Comment: Tried this but I end up with the two buttons taking place of my label

Comment: Have you constrained your label properly? `Top: SuperView(set suitable distance)` , `leading: superView`, `trailing: superView` and  `aspectRatio`. Now connect the top of both buttons to the label

Answer (score 3):

You should do this using UIStackView. This needs iOS 9 as target. If you are on a lower version, you can use [TZSTackView](https://github.com/tomvanzummeren/TZStackView)

Answer (score 0):

simply use TableView with custom tableview cell by putting uilabel on the top and uibuttons below and set the constraints using **size inspector > Autoresizing** ..

Answer (score 0):

Its easy just follow these steps.
use tableview for this.

**1**.take 2 views First for your top stuff and second for button.

**2**.add constraint on 1st view.
    **2.1** add top,leading,trailing and give equal width to the context view   and change the multiplier to 0.5;

**3**.add constraint on Second view leading ,trailing and bottom and top to first view.

**3.1** add button inside second view and give leading ,top , bottom and equal width to parent view and change multiplier to 0.5.

**3.2** add second button and put top,bottom ,trailing and horizontal spacing to first button to zero.

Comment: Tried this, but I end up with the 2 buttons stacked on the first half of my first view ..

Comment: instead of bottom constraint on 2 view use equal height with first view.

Comment: Ok I'm trying, but where does the TableView takes place ?

Comment: Yes but in your example I did not understand where the TableView takes place ?